# Texmaker file not found when I use reledmac

Tags: errors, texmaker, reledmac

All of a sudden yesterday, after using reledmac on Texmaker for years (or days), I could no longer make a PDF. It shows up with "file not found" on a new document, or it just reloads the last successful PDF on the old one. After playing around with it I found it only happens when I have `reledmac` active. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling reledmac for some reason, and even uninstalling and reinstalling miktex (no idea why I did that). I can't figure out what's wrong. I definitely do have it installed and it worked until yesterday.

The first time I tried making the PDF but failing was after trying to using Xarrangement. It case that helps.

EDIT!!!!!:::::
I've isolated the problem to the following piece of code I have in the beginning of my document. This code didn't give me trouble before, but I found that if I got rid of it my new problem disappears:

```
\begin{pairs}
\begin{Leftside}
\beginnumbering
            \pstart[\section*
                {
                    \begin{flushleft}
                        Joshua
                    \end{flushleft}
                }
            ] \hidenumbering
\pend \endnumbering \end{Leftside} \begin{Rightside} \beginnumbering \pstart[\section*
{\begin{flushright} יהושע \end{flushright}] \hidenumbering
\pend \endnumbering \end{Rightside} \end{pairs} \Columns
```

Here's what I have in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{book}

%Set Hebrew font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english} \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage{cjhebrew} %I need this for using Hebrew in text commands

%Set special formatting
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\Xwrapcontent[A]{\LR}

\firstlinenum{1}
\linenumincrement{1}
\setRlineflag{} %Removes R
\Xbeforeinserting[A]{\RTL}
%   \Xbhookgroup[A]{\flushright}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A,B] \Xgroupbyline[A]
\Xlemmaseparator[A]{[} %Fixes the direction of the bracket
\Xlemmaseparator[B]{]}
\Xlemmafont[B]{\bfseries}

\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.42\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.42\textwidth}
\setlength{\ledlsnotewidth}{0.1\textwidth}
\linenummargin{right} \linenummarginR{left}
\setlength{\linenumsep}{0.5pc}

%   \renewcommand{\ledlsnotefontsetup}{\raggedright\scriptsize}

\def\linenumrepR#1{
    \begingroup%
        \hebrewfont%
        \hebrewnumeral{#1}
    \endgroup
}

\firstlinenumR{1}
\linenumincrementR{1}

\usepackage{bidi}
\makeatletter
\let\Afootnoterule=\right@footnoterule
\makeatother


\tolerance=100000 %Fix justification issues
```

Comment: And now, somehow, I've solved my problem. I have no idea how.

Comment: if possible write and answer how it was resolved otherwise you can voluntaritly delete your question